# pass structure to kernel local memory

Tags: memory, local, opencl

I have problem with passing structure to kernel local memory. Here is the kernel kode:

```
typedef struct data {
    unsigned long wId;  // group_id
    unsigned long iId[1];   // global_item_id
} DATA;

__kernel void tKernel(__global DATA *x, __local DATA tmp) {
    int wd = get_work_dim();

    // x dimension
    int xGrId = get_group_id(0);
    int xLId = get_local_id(0);
    int xGlId = get_global_id(0);

    x += xGrId;
    x->wId = tmp.wId;
    x->iId[xLId] = ++tmp.wId;

}
```

Here is the host code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE (1)
#define LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE (1)
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

typedef struct data {
    unsigned long wId;
    unsigned long iId[LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE];
} DATA;

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;

    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = NULL;

    cl_mem cmPinnedBufOut = NULL;
    DATA *cDataOut = NULL;

    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;

    size_t group_size = GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE / LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE;

    FILE *fp;
    const char fileName[] = "./kernel.cl";
    size_t source_size;
    char *source_str;

    /* Load kernel source file */
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    source_str = (char *)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

     /* Create OpenCL Context */
    context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create command queue with measurment of preformance */
    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /* Create memory object */
    cmPinnedBufOut = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, group_size * sizeof(DATA), NULL, &ret);
    cDataOut = (DATA *)malloc(group_size * sizeof(DATA));

    /* Create kernel program from source file */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {   
        printf("\nFail to build the program\n");
        char buffer[10240];
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Create data parallel OpenCL kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "tKernel", &ret);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    /* Set OpenCL kernel arguments */
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cmPinnedBufOut);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    DATA tmp;
    tmp.wId = 66;
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(DATA), &tmp);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    size_t global_item_size = GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE;
    size_t local_item_size = LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE;

    /* Execute OpenCL kernel as data parallel */
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret == CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE) {
        printf("Invalid work group size: error when compute group size: %lu/%lu", global_item_size, local_item_size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    /* Transfer result to host */
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, cmPinnedBufOut, CL_TRUE, 0, group_size * sizeof(DATA), cDataOut, 0, NULL, NULL);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    /* Display Results */
    for (int i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
        printf("%d: -> group_id %lu ~> work_item_ids: ", i, cDataOut[i].wId);
        for (int j = 0; j < LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE; j++)
            printf("%2lu, ", cDataOut[i].iId[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");    

    /* Finalization */
    ret = clFlush(commandQueue);
    ret = clFinish(commandQueue);  // blockink function, wait until all queue cmd are finished
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);

    free(source_str);

    return 0;
}
```

So I expected as result **0: -> group_id 66 ~> work_item_ids:  67,**
But I get **0: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  1,**
From this I conclude that the **hh** structure with the number 66 was not reading correctly
by the kernel. I try to put this same way on integer number and this works perfectly.
So my question is, am I doing something wrong, or there isn't way to copy data structure from host to device local memory, or is there another way to doing this?

Comment: pierre tautou: I need your help at this point. I am working on the similar problem you have stated above. Have you found your solution? Is the above structure declaration inside the kernel is really allowed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clSetKernelArg` for `__local` buffers only specifies the size, and the pointer must be 0. See OpenCL spec 5.7.2.  There is no way you can initialize local memory from the host.